# How to ExecuteSqlCommand in Entity Framework without it being contained in a transaction

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to execute a stored procedure with Entity Framework.

Normally I call it like this:

```
this.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC edi_UploadTransmission");
```

However, this particular stored procedure includes accessing a linked server.

Since EF wraps `ExecuteSqlCommand` in a transaction, it is failing, as a linked server is not supported in a transaction (as far as I can tell).

Is there a way to execute this stored procedure with Entity Framework without it being in a transaction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pass `TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction` as the first parameter to the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

For example,

```
this.Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "EXEC edi_UploadTransmission");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That parameter ended half a day of trying to get that stuff running.

Comment: @smistry, see https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4882 "There is currently no logic in ExecuteSqlCommand to begin or end transactions. The underlying RelationalCommand will make use of the transaction if one in associated with the RelationalConnection."

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to simply not use EF for this part of your code. You can freely combine EF with straight ADO.NET code or with other ORMs such as Dapper or Chain.

https://github.com/docevaad/Chain/wiki/A-Chain-comparison-to-Dapper